# Infinispan : Local cache only

Tags: java, infinispan

I'm using **Infinispan (7.2.3.Final)** to store data into multiples caches.

The thing is : I only want to store datas locally, into files. I don't want to store datas into memory to avoid memory issues.

I get this error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: As far I known, Infinyspan is a distributed memory, so its main purpose is to use RAM memory. So why do you choose Infinispan and not a data base (for example)?

Comment: I choose Infinispan because it's dead simple to use.

Comment: Simplicity depends on the use case. You can configure Infinispan persistence (http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#persistence), but it won't be simpler than to use a database directly, my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinispan is a Java distributed in-memory. So I don't think it is relevant to use it if you don't want to use RAM. In my opinion, a good usage of Infinispan means you will have tune the memory (size and eviction) to find a good tradeoff between the running-cost, the complexity, and the performance.

You can configure Infinispan to persist data ([doc](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#persistence)). And you can configure it to evict data from RAM memory ([doc](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#eviction_anchor)). But I cannot advice a real configuration if you do not describe your use-case, and in particular why you think you need Infinispan (why not a data base?)

A possible usage is to keep all-in-memory. Obviously your data has to be small enough (I don't give number, some people can accept to pay several machines to reduce latency, it depends on your business...)

Ten year ago, we could use them to simply batch insertions in a data base. Now we use Kafka for this use case.

A frequent usage is keep hot data in memory. In this case we configure eviction and persistence. I think you are looking for eviction strategies [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#eviction_anchor). There are several eviction strategies. But as far I know none allows to not use RAM at all: objects will pass through the memory, at least during the persistence.